# How to position images next to text using CSS

Tags: css, layout, html

I have problem with CSS with two divs.
My first div contain texts while second div contains images. I need to put the image div in top right corner of text div.

My div structures as below:

```
<div class="text">text text text .... more text</div>
<div class="images">image image</div>
```

I want to archieve this:

========================

text text  *- image -*

text text  *- image -*

text text text text

text text text text

text text text text

=========================

I  illustred this problem with an image:
[image]

How to achieve this?

Comment: Isn't the word "problem" illegal in question titles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Float the image?](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)**

```
<style>.images { float: right; }</style>

<div class="images">image image</div>
<div class="text">text text text .... more text</div>
```

**[Live Example](http://dabblet.com/gist/2479230)** - This example demonstrates the principle. It has more styles to make it look nicer, but it will work without them. Play with it and see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks Truth. Using float will float the image to the right and text to the left, this make two vertical bars, right bar contains texts and left bar contains images. The result I wish to archive is text on right, images on left and the text more than the high of the image will goes bellow images. This link will better explain what I need. [link](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/8gpb3)

Comment: No one said to float the text to the left, you misunderstood me. I'll post an example soon. @user1351358

Comment: @tanyx: If this answer was helpful for you, consider accepting it by clicking the large tick mark underneath the question's score.

Answer (score 2):

If you reformat the HTML to put the images in the text ,  you can float the images within that container and the text will flow around it.

```
<style>
  img { float:right; }
</style>
<div>
    <img src="image1.png">
    <img src="image1.png">
    Lorum ipsum .....
</div>
```

Placing the images into a different container means they're 'separated' from that text,  so the text can't flow.